# How to build my models correctly?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am using django to wirte a program now, my problem is i am confused with building models.
I have made two models in seperate apps, which is user and device. The relationship is user can borrow 1 to n devices, but each device can be hold by only one user. Then, in the user class, i need to have a attribute borrowed_device that can store the device classes(all the devices he borrowed), and in Device class, i need a attribute that can help me track who borrowed this device.

The following is my code, and i don't how to write then, any advice would be appreciated.

user/models

```
from django.db import models
from device.models import Device


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    borrowed_device = models.ForeignKey('Device', on_delete=models.CASCADE(), related_name='borrowed_device')
    # id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('username', )
```

device/models

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User


class Device(models.Model):
    DEVICE_TYPE = {('chemistry', 'chemistry'), ('physics', 'physics'), ('computer', 'computer'), ('biology', 'biology')}
    device_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DEVICE_TYPE)
    bought_in_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_used_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE(), related_name='user')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('type', '-bought_in_time')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that a user can hold 1 .. n devices, so there exists one to many relationship between user and device models as follows:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    borrowed_device = models.ManyToManyField('Device' )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('username', )
```

You don't need `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE(), related_name='user')` field in your Device model.

`device.user_set.all()` will retrieve all the users associated with that particular device.
So, in your case you just need to assure that that particular device is associated with any users or not. If not, you can add the device to User manytomanyfield.

Comment: thank you, and i still got a question tha how can i store the history of User borroing devices, eg. people A borrow Device a1, and how to save the borrow history in a attribute? i mean all the devices he had borrowed. Should i make a list in the User to store it or anything else?

Comment: @Richard, if you want to maintain a history. you should have a different column(manytomany) in the model representing history/log of the devices. You will simply add in the that column ,never remove from that Or, you can have another model(HISTORY) with two columns(user, devices) and save on that model as well.